# Can you display a unique (counting) number on each printed page in Word/Publisher?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-office-2010, numbering, microsoft-publisher

I have a one page document where in the header I would like to have a number starting from one, that changes on every printed page. So if I printed out a batch of 50, the first printed sheet would have the number 1, and so on until page 50.

I could copy and paste the page 50 times and then use page numbers, but that is not ideal.

I am using Office 2010, and the document is currently in Publisher, but if it is possible in Word I can switch to Word.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this using a mail merge. If you create an Excel sheet with the numbers in, you can insert that field into a mail merge document. You just need to keep track of numbers that have been used in the excel sheet.